# Need help: Stack using a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, stack, implementation, prefix-operator

I got to solve this program, but I don't really know how to use a Stack using a pointer.
If there's anyone that could explain that to me, I would be grateful.

Implement a.t.p. Stack using a pointer and write a subroutine that calculates the value of a logical expression given in prefix form. You need to solve the problem using the stack.
Input: a string that represents a logical expression in prefix form
Output: the value of the loaded expression
For example, the input data:

```
|0&1|^010
```

should write:
1
Note: `& = AND, | = OR, ^ = XOR, - = NOT`

(P.S. Excuse me if there's any mistake, english is not my mother tongue)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: You could also try this reading: http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html#sec-4-1

Answer (score 0):

1. First make a Stack data structure,
2. Take care of operator precedence (if any),
3. Convert your expression string to [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)
4. Evaluate using [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

This question should be of help to you - 
[How to evaluate arithmetic expression using stack c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443251/how-to-evaluate-arithmetic-expression-using-stack-c/19443381#19443381).

Comment: "Take care of operator precedence (if any)", in `C`!?

Comment: @StoryTeller - His question is regarding evaluating an expression using stack. `write a subroutine that calculates the value of a logical expression given in prefix form`

Comment: Right. My bad. Although "First make a Stack data structure," when the question is basically "How do I make a stack structure" is a little dodgy.

Comment: I know how to make a Stack data structure but I don't know how to use it in the main program

Comment: the problem is that I don't know what's the difference between a Stack using a pointer and a Stack using a field? I know how to evaluate expressions using a stack

Comment: @user3041602 - It depends how the person gave you this task understands this, you should ask this to the questioner.